# SQL. Stats Users table by age range

Tags: sql

I have a table with the date of birth of my platform users and I need to sort them by age ranges (18-25, 25-35, etc) for a back-office stat project. They already are sorted by gender.

Here is my code:

```
public function GenreByAge() {


        $date_day = new datetime();
        $date_day = $date_day->format('Y-m-d');


        $sql = "SELECT count(*)  as nb, id_thematique, dn 
                FROM qr_thematique_preco q 
                INNER JOIN users as u ON u.id_user = q.id_membre
                WHERE u.id_part = '$this->id_part'
                AND u.sexe = '$this->genre'";


       switch ($this->tranche_age) {

            case 1:

                $sql .= AND DATE_FORMAT(dn,'%Y-%m-%d') <= date_sub(curdate(), INTERVAL 18 YEAR) 
                        AND DATE_FORMAT(dn,'%Y-%m-%d') > date_sub(curdate(), INTERVAL 26 YEAR);

                break;


            case 2:

                $sql .= AND dn <= date_sub(curdate(), INTERVAL 26 YEAR) 
                        AND dn > date_sub(curdate(), INTERVAL 36 YEAR);

                break;


            case 3:

                $sql .= AND dn <= date_sub(curdate(), INTERVAL 36 YEAR) 
                        AND dn > date_sub(curdate(), INTERVAL 46 YEAR);

                break;


            case 4:

                $sql .= AND dn <= date_sub(curdate(), INTERVAL 46 YEAR) 
                        AND dn > date_sub(curdate(), INTERVAL 56 YEAR);

                break;


            case 5:

                $sql .= AND dn <= date_sub(curdate(), INTERVAL 56 YEAR) 
                        AND dn > date_sub(curdate(), INTERVAL 66 YEAR);

                break;
```

But the query doesn't return anything with my data.

Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You have written your `WHERE` conditions wrong and they are mutually exclusive.

For example, a date of birth cannot be at the same time less than 18 years in the past and more than 26 years in the past.

```
AND DATE_FORMAT(dn,'%Y-%m-%d') <= date_sub(curdate(), INTERVAL 18 YEAR) 
AND DATE_FORMAT(dn,'%Y-%m-%d') > date_sub(curdate(), INTERVAL 26 YEAR);
```

(a person cannot be younger than 18 years and older than 26 at the same time).

I suggest you use `BETWEEN` if you want to generate intervals of dates in which to capture a particular date range.

```
AND DATE_FORMAT(dn,'%Y-%m-%d') 
    BETWEEN date_sub(curdate(), INTERVAL 26 YEAR) AND 
            date_sub(curdate(), INTERVAL 18 YEAR);
```

Alternatively, you can just switch the rules in your already existing conditions to:

```
AND DATE_FORMAT(dn,'%Y-%m-%d') >= date_sub(curdate(), INTERVAL 18 YEAR) 
AND DATE_FORMAT(dn,'%Y-%m-%d') < date_sub(curdate(), INTERVAL 26 YEAR);
```

Comment: It works. Thank you very much. I'll blame myself forever for such an obvious mistake!! Guess I'll slow down on cafeine.

Comment: @Mateus Well, it's good that it was just a small change. Please don't forget the "rewards".

Comment: @mateus or perhaps increase the caffeine :)

Comment: @Mateus If this answer has been helped you solve your problem, please don't forget to upvote/mark the question as correct.